# Where to write facts on puppet master?

Tags: puppet

Anyone tell me the path of file where we define the facts on puppet master.
I m using facter version 1.6.6

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places you can put them. Please refer to http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html for full details.

The way I like to do it is using the "pluginsync". I have a module named "custom". I have $modulepath/custom/lib/facter/.rb

On older versions you will need to make sure that pluginsync=true is in [main] on your master and agents, newer versions of puppet have this on by default.

More information on this method of distributing facts/functions/types/etc can be found at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html